# React: Having issues with using contexts with setting the value in the same file as the context declaration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm fixing some prop drilling that was going on in my project. My app.js currently queries every 5 seconds for database health, as well as defines contexts for a few variables.
I'm having issues in fetching the setter from the context.

App.js (provider side):

```
ConnectionContext=React.createContext({})

const App = () => {
    const [isConnectedtoDB,setConnectedtoDB]=useState({isConnected:{}});
    const setConnected=useContext(ConnectionContext)
    useInterval(() => {
        const health = (await health.get()).data
        if(Date.now() - health.connection.time_last_message > 10000){
            setConnected({isConnected:false})
        } else{
            setConnected({isConnected:health.connection.alive})
    },5000)
```

navbar.js (Consumer side):

```
const NavBar = () =>{
    const {isConnected}=useContext(ConnectionContext)
    return (
        {isConnected ? &&
            <p>I'm alive!</p>
        })
```

I saw online that one solution was to wrap the setting in a UseEffect block but I'm fairly certain you can't nest UseEffect within UseInterval as UseInterval is itself defined by a UseEffect block.
useInterval is exported from another file as follows:

```
export const useInterval = (callback,delay) => {
    const savedCallback = useRef()
    useEffect(() => {
        function tick() {
            savedCallback.current()
        }
        if (delay !== null) {
            let id = setInterval(tick,delay)
            return () => clearInterval(id)
        }
    },[delay]}
}
```

The error I'm getting is that setConnected is not a function

Comment: The context provider isn't supposed to use the context. It's suppose to supply a value to it using `ConnectionContext.Provider`. Only the consumer side should have a call to `useContext`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the context in the parent component which is expected just to provide value to the consumer

The setConnected should be your local state

```
const [connected, setConnected] = useState({});
```

You need to feed the state value from the parent(provider) to the child (consumer).

**Example**:

Parent.js

```
import React, {createContext, useState} from 'react';

export const ExampleContext = createContext();

function Parent(props){
    
   const [isConnected, setConnected] = useState({})


   useInterval(() => {
        const health = (await health.get()).data;

        if(Date.now() - health.connection.time_last_message > 10000){
            setConnected({isConnected:false})
        } else{

            setConnected({isConnected:health.connection.alive})
    },5000)

   return (
       <ExampleContext.Provider value={{ isConnected }}>
            {props.children}
       </ExampleContext.Provider>
   )
}

export default Parent;
```

Child.js

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import {ExampleContext} from './Parent';


function Child(){
    const { isConnected } = useContext(ExampleContext);

    return(
        <div>
            {<button> Context in Action: { isConnected } </button>}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Child;
```

In your main App.js file you will render child.js as children for parent.js

```
  <Parent>
      <Child />
   </Parent>
```